# Printing numers without using PHP inbuild functions

Tags: php

```
$numbers = array(3,5,6,7,8,11);
$missing = array();
for ($i = 3; $i < 11; $i++) {
    if (!in_array($i, $numbers)){
        $missing[] = $i;
    }
}
```

I want to find the missing numbers from `3` to `11` without using PHP innuild function, i have tried but i haven't not completed fully.

In this code i have used `in_array` but without this i have to do. any one help here.I am new to PHP using PHP inbuild i can do this, but this is not my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `foreach` loop inside on `$numbers` and check for the value of `$i`. Declare a flag variable, say `$found` to `false`. While looping inside if we get the number, set `$found` to `true` and exit the loop. In the end, if `$found` still stays as false, add the current `$i` to the result.

```
<?php

$numbers = array(3,5,6,7,8,11);
$missing = array();

for ($i = 3; $i <= 11; $i++) {
    $found = false;
    foreach($numbers as $value){
        if($value === $i){
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if(!$found) $missing[] = $i;
}


print_r($missing);
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/9d12f)

Answer (score -1):

you can use [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) same as :

```
$numbersOrigin = range(3, 11);
$numbers = array(3,5,6,7,8,11);

$missing = array_diff($numbersOrigin, $numbers);
```

unuse buildIn functions :

```
$numbers = array(3,5,6,7,8,11);
$missing = array();
$index = 0;
for ($i = 3; $i < 11; $i++) {
   if ($numbers[$index] === $i) {
         $index++;
   } else {
      $missing[] = $i;
   }
}
```

Comment: It is actually without using built in functions.

Comment: i 've just edited

Comment: Ok (didn't downvote).

Comment: =))))) okie, I don't pay attention to `built in`